# Javascript and django, "there is no locally stored liblary for the HTTP"

Tags: javascript, html, pycharm

How can I solve it, I was searching in google, without result?

Error message:

> There is no locally stored library for the HTTP link.
>   Checks that URL of an external JavaScript library is associated with a locally stored file used for code completion and navigation. Use 'Download library' quick fix (Alt+Enter) to solve the problem.

My template:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "ckeditor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js" %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "ckeditor/ckeditor-init.js" %}"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="./">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <p><input type="submit" value="post"></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

After insert "http:" behind I still have this problem.

Comment: Does it work? "There is no locally..." it's just Intellij(PyCharm) warning that you don't have a local copy of the library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to download that library or use it from web like this:

```
<script src"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you are connected to the Internet. Click on the link, press Alt+Enter, then Enter again. PyCharm will download the JS file, store it locally, and make the warning go away.

Alternatively, you can click on the link, then in the light bulb, then on "Download library".

You don't need a locally stored JS library, however. Your templates will work just as well, as long as you are online.

Answer (score 0):

Please include the text of your error and the code causing it, not a screenshot.

You need `http:` in front of the `//` on the line in question.